# String and StringBuilder, while using equals()

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

```
String s = new String("Abc");
StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("Abc");
System.out.println(s.equals(s1));
```

Output: false

Why ?? Can anyone explain me about this?

Comment: The main reason for this behaviour is due to this line in code of String class equals method: 
1017           if (anObject instanceof String) {      // hence if an Object passed in equals method must be an instanceOf String only.  Otherwise it always returns false.

Answer (score 3):

A `String` is not a `StringBuilder`, so why do you expect them to be equal?

```
s.equals(s1.toString())
```

will return true, since that would be a comparison of two `String`s.

`String`'s `equals` is implemented as :

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        ...
    }
    return false;
}
```

When `anObject` is not an instance of `String` (and only `String` can be an instance of `String`, since the `String` class is final), `equals` returns false.

Comment: can you please elaborate

Answer (score -1):

> Java provides the StringBuffer and String classes, and the String class is used to manipulate character strings that cannot be changed. Simply stated, objects of type String are read only and immutable. The StringBuffer class is used to represent characters that can be modified.

In this case when you have:

```
  String s = new String("Abc");
  StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("Abc");
  System.out.println(s.equals(s1));
```

Gives `false` because in StringBuffer class `equals` method is not overriden as in String class.
Therefore you first need to convert that to a String and then use equals method like this:

```
s.equals(s1.toString()) gives `true`
```